# How does numerical objects in Ruby exclude dot notation?

Tags: ruby, object, methods

I notice that dot notation is required in a majority of the cases to call an object's method. I assume the dot is used to connect the object with the method name, but in arithmetic operations, there is a space between the number object and its operation method. For example,

```
7.-(5)
```

uses dot notation and can also be written as

```
7 - 5
```

with optional spaces in between the operator and the operands. How is it able to perform the method call?

Comment: Just as a comparison in Python `2+2` is the same as `(2).__add__(2)` (don't know Ruby's semantics though).

Comment: Any more confusion do you have? please let us know. I will then accordingly update in my answer. I hope you now catch the fact.

Comment: @RubyLovely, thanks for the source to RubyMonk. It explained that "Ruby makes an exception in its syntactic rules for commonly used operators so you don't have to use periods to invoke them on objects." It seems my confusion stems from the implementation of these rules. How can they enable a numerical object to perform a method call if the numerical object is separated by the operator method and the preceding numerical object in the expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Syntactic Sugar for Special Methods`](http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/chapters/6-objects/lessons/37-syntactic-sugar-for-special-methods) good source to know all syntactic sugar of ruby.

The all are below are same in Ruby.

```
2 + 3   #=> 5
2.+(3)  #=> 5
2.+ 3 #=> 5
```

so when you write `2 + 3`, it is happening internally as `2.+(3)` or `2.+ 3`

As everything in Ruby is an object. and here `2` also a `Fixnum` object. With `.` we are calling object `2` 's `+` method,that's it.

```
2.class #=> Fixnum
2.instance_of? Fixnum #=> true
2.respond_to? :+  #=> true
```

Another example follows below:

```
"a" + "b" #=> "ab"
"a".+"b" #=> "ab"
"a".respond_to? :+ #=> true
```

`respond_to` returned `true` - this is because `String` class has the concatenation method `+`. Being a object of String class `'a'` could call `+` method by passing `b` as an argument to that method.

Comment: Good answer. You might want to mention the special case of the unary minus too.

Comment: The link you gave is only giving some of the syntactic sugar. It doesn't list all, e.g. `-@`, `!`, `[]=`, ...

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune Yes,you are right. :) But I tried to give him a conceptual idea. But one of the answerer did the job already on behalf of me. :) so I didn't.

Answer (score 2):

> so how is it [the number object] able to perform the method call?

The number object doesn't have to figure it out, Ruby handles it internally. And it works for any object, not just numbers:

```
class Foo
  def +(arg)
    puts "adding #{arg}"
  end
end

Foo.new + "bar"
# => adding bar
```

Comment: This is precisely what I was trying to understand. Unfortunately, I can't even upvote it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While Ruby is more orthogonal than Python, that doesn’t mean that it is perfectly orthogonal. So, it also has its anomalies, for example, it also has a `for` keyword (that is translated for a call to each):

```
for x in (1..3) do
  puts x
end
```

Just because it has it, doesn't mean it is good for you to use. No one really recommends using methods like `for`, because it is better to use `each`, as I'm sure you already read.

Calling a `+` method with a `.`, or sending the message `+` to your object, is something that is not worth doing just to keep the language really, truly, orthogonal.

You can see a [gramatic](http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/~regan/cse305/RubyBNF.pdf) for Ruby and this might help you to find other non-orthogonal aspects if you are interested in this aspect.

Comment: `for` is not a method, it is a keyword. And it translates into a call to `each`.

Answer (score 0):

> How is it able to perform the method call?

Well, this is called [*syntactic sugar*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar). It's really nothing special. It's just *an exception* to the common ruby method calling rules in order to make the code a little bit more understandable and possibly readable.

Would you understand `7.-(5)` faster than `7 - 5`? I don't think so. And that's the reason this *exception* exists.

It is possible because the Ruby interpreter reads any `x - y` and translates it to `x.-y` as well as `x[y]` is translated to `x.[](y)` or `x[y] = z` is translated into `x.[]=(y, z)`.

Here's a list of all syntactic sugar calling notations:

[image]

The image is taken from a very good book called [*The Well-Grounded Rubyist*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988657) which covers this concept in part 2, chapter 7.